# React JS - onChange function is being triggered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an issue while working with date input in react. so the date value is coming from *graphQL* and format of date is `dd.mm.yyyy` but in order to set a default value for HTML date input I am converting format to `yyyy.mm.dd` and for saving data again I need to do vice versa.

I am saving date in state and calling on change function to update values and converting formats.

the problem is that this function is being triggered twice `onChange` and returning `NaN-NaN-NaN` (on 2nd run) but not each time only sometimes (weird). And, with some dates, it works fine, for example, with `02.03.2000` no error and executed only once.

with **24** it called ***twice*** and error on 2nd call (see screenshot). maybe conversion is wrong somehow? and if I remove `defaultValue` from input then it called only once.

[image]

```js
state = {
    newUser: {
      geburtsdatum: "01.02.2000"
    }
}

ConvertDate(htmlDate, format) {
    var date = new Date(htmlDate);
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
      dd = "0" + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = "0" + mm;
    }
    if (format === "graphql") date = dd + "." + mm + "." + yyyy;
    if (format === "html") date = yyyy + "-" + dd + "-" + mm;
    return date;
}

onChange = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    if (e.target.type === "date") {
      value = this.convertDate(value, "graphql");
    console.log(value, name);
    }
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        newUser: {
          ...prevState.newUser,
          [name]: value
        }
      };
    });
  };

<input
    type="date"
    name="geburtsdatum"
    defaultValue={this.convertDate(this.state.newUser.geburtsdatum, "html")}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    placeholder={this.getDJHTooltip("geburtsdatum")}
/>
```

Comment: What is `ConvertDate`? A functional component? there is no `return` method

Comment: it returns date with given format.

Comment: So where is your `render` function? what is this `<input` element in the middle of the code, without any context?

Comment: Why doesn't your input have a value prop passed to it? defaultValue prop is only for the initial render. Use the "value" prop instead of "defaultValue" and see if your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is called twice because you are calling it twice in your render method.

1. 1st Call: **On input:** onChange() calls the ConvertDate() method and sets state. On setting state component re-renders
2. 2nd Call: Component re-renders and the ConvertDate() method is called when getting defaultValue

I would recommend storing the defaultValue in state and retrieving that value from state instead of calling a function in the render method.

You receive NaN-NaN-NaN because an invalid date is being passed to your function "ConvertDate". The reason might be that the date you receive from API is incorrect in some way. Try using [momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) for date handling and conversion, its relatively simple and you can avoid bugs

**Edit:**
Javascript Date() constructor accepts these two formats "yyyy-mm-dd" or "mm-dd-yyyy".

```js
console.log(new Date("2019-12-14")); // valid yyyy-mm-dd
console.log(new Date("2019-14-12")); // invalid yyyy-dd-mm

console.log(new Date("12-14-2019")); // valid mm-dd-yyyy
console.log(new Date("14-12-2019")); // invalid dd-mm-yyyy
```

**Update:**
MomentJS is [not the recommended](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) library for manipulating dates anymore, as it is outdated and there are much better and smaller alternatives available.

Comment: onChange function is being called twice, and if I remove defaultValue from input then it doesn't. I think while setting defaultValue it triggers onChange event too. But why is the problem with certain dates not alll.

Comment: The format for date that javascript Date() constructor expects is mm.dd.yyyy or yyyy.mm.dd. The problem is with dates that have value greater than "12" for the first 2 characters because there can only be 12 months.